# wmi "log on as" property of a service

Tags: vb.net, wmi, wmi-query

i am trying to write a service monitor tool like services.msc
where can the attribute "log on as" be found using WMI

thanks

erez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Setting Windows Service Account - C# and WMI](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2007/05/08/setting-windows-service-account-c-and-wmi.aspx) has some c# that might help - it should be easy enough to [convert](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) it to VB.

Specifically, the [comment by asbf](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2007/05/08/setting-windows-service-account-c-and-wmi.aspx#5616103) looks to have what you need.

```
string serviceName = "eventLog";
System.Management.SelectQuery query = new System.Management.SelectQuery(string.Format("select name, startname from Win32_Service where name = '{0}'", serviceName));
using (System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
{
   foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject service in searcher.Get())
   {
       Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0} - Logon : {1} ", service["Name"], service["startname"]));
   }
}
```